# Chrome Extension, scrollTop=0 enywhere

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, scroll

I'm making a chrome extension. And I've some problems with scrollTop (I hope this is the "get scroll height"!).

First: structure: I've a manifest, an html page, a javascript, and an image.

Second: Aim. I'm trying to scroll down to bottom, than go to top, and restart to scroll to bottom.. a loop.
In manifest I've this:

```
{
 "background": {
       "page": "scroll.html"
 },
 "browser_action": {
       "default_icon": "icon.png",
       "default_title": ""
 },
 "content_scripts": [ {
       "js": [ "scroll.js" ],
       "matches": [ "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ]
 } ],
 "description": "Auto Scroll. UpDownUp!",
 "icons": {
       "128": "icon.png",
       "48": "icon.png"
 },    
 "manifest_version": 2,    
 "name": "Auto Scroll, UpDownUp",    
 "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],    
 "version": "0.2.3"
}
```

As you see I don't have any pop up html.

In my html page i've this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Auto Scroll</title>
</head>
<body >
<script src="scroll.js"></script>
</body> 
</html>
```

And In my scroll.js there are several functions, to start scrolling, and scrolling faster.
But I don't need to quote all that code (164 lines).

I've simply a lot of trash, and at the end it does only this simple thing:

```
chrome.tabs.update(id, {'url': 'javascript:document.body.scrollTop+=1;'});
```

My extension "works". But I've not done all what I wanted:

This extension will only go down (and it does!!). I want that when I'm at bottom of page, the extension will execute:

```
chrome.tabs.update(id, {'url': 'javascript:document.body.scrollTop=0;'});
```

And I thought:

1) get max scroll height, check with scrolltop, if same, use that code. If i do so, the extension will always go on top (after a little scroll down), as if these values are always(!!) equals.

```
if(document.body.scollTop==document.body.Height)
{
chrome.tabs.update(id, {'url': 'javascript:document.body.scrollTop=0;'});
}
```

this is the result of first try... but doesn't works.

2) var y=document.body.scrollTop --> scroll --> z=document.body.scrollTop. If y==z, then I'm on bottom, then go to top... this doesn't works, y and z are always equals!!!

I used an alert(value) every time I use

```
chrome.tabs.update(id, {'url': 'javascript:document.body.scrollTop+=1;'});
```

set as

```
alert(document.body.scollTop);
```

and pop up appear with "0". Always... I close the pop up, the extension scroll down a bit more, and pop up appear and there is 0 again!

Ok... I'ts my fault!?

I've an idea: my javascript is loaded by a background page, and the javascript act on a page in browser, mybe the scrollTop command give me background page height... and this is really BAD. 
Can you help me finding the way to stop at end of "active" page to execute the "go-to-top" function!?

Edit:

I found something, if I use this

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    alert(tab.url);
})
```

a window pop us telling me the acqual tab url. Looking at [this](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#type-Tab) I find that height is the tab properties, so I use:

```
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { 
    alert(tab.height);
})
```

but the window popup and say "undefined" .... I really don't know what I've to do to retrieve the actual tab scroll position.

Comment: Hi, welcome to [so].  I'd just to clarify something: are you looking to scroll a background page or the page being currently viewed by the user?

Comment: If my memory serves me, you might be accessing a non-editable value by using `scrollTop`. If you want to modify the value, I believe you have to call a function. I forgot what it is, though :(. Good luck!

Comment: hi @Qantas94Heavy, thanks. I'm actually scrolling the visibile page, not the background one. I'm able to scroll it, i've already done. The question is: how I see the max scollTop value of the page user is seeing? 
Bean5 I'm not trying to edit "scrollTop" value, becouse I'm already able tpo do that with the code I posted. thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, finally.
I managed to do a all in 2 functions:

```
function scrolla(){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({code: 'var x= document.body.scrollTop; document.body.scrollTop+=1; var y=document.body.scrollTop; if(x==y){document.body.scrollTop=0;}'});
}
```

and

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

      var start = setInterval(function(){scrolla()},10);

    });
```

This will scroll the page untill the end, than restart from top. 
I manged to do this very very hardly! HAHHA Solved!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing background page code and actual webpage code.

1 will definitely not work because you are querying the value of the background page and not of the actual web page (the condition) and then executing the code in the actual web page (setting the scrollTop).

Regarding 2 - I am not sure what you meant there...

The proper way to execute JavaScript within an actual web page, from a background page, is using [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript). Or you can just use a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) (you might not even need a background page?).

Once you make sure you execute all of the code (that is meant to query and change stuff in an actual web page) in the actual web page and not in the background page, you code should generally work.

Comment: BUt i'm doint it in this way... content script are injected by a background html page, and with chrome.tab function I act on the page. I think no one understood (maybe I was misleading) my question: I don't find scrolltop value of the active page... only this, i repeat, my extension works! it scrolls the active page! Thanks anyway ^^

Comment: Using chrome.tabs.update with a JavaScript URL is not the right way. Use executeScript, this is exactly its purpose. If no one understood your question, then try asking it more clearly. And cut it down a bit, it is too long, which probably makes it even more unclear.

Comment: And no code you have shown is actually supposed to get the scrollTop of the page, it looks like you always try to get the scrollTop of the background page. Perhaps a more complete example would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

1) You shouldn't use tabs.update to inject javascript: urls -- instead use tabs.executeScript to inject code. javascript: urls are less secure because they inject code directly into the webpages world, whereas executeScript injects code into the separate world of contentscripts

2) You can return values using tabs.executeScript -- but only if the code that you run is synchronous. Just list the return value in a final statement of the code (no return keyword) e.g. `chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabid,{code:"var a = 34; location.href;"},function(url){console.log(url)})` will return the value of location.href to the callback function.

3) You should be able to scroll by setting *elem*.scrollTop = *value*. *value* ranges from 0 to *elem*.scrollHeight. If you can't scroll using document.body.scrollTop then it may be a different element in the page that needs to be scrolled.